# Covert the curl command into php

Tags: php, curl

I have tried to convert the curl command from https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ URL. but they are not giving me proper php code for that. Can you please help out.

```
curl -i -F account_id=12345 -F authhash=BKPda_T497AX4EjBsk3ttw9OcOzk -F audioFile=@CasioVoice.wav  https://url/upload
```

I tried this code to convert into php code. but not getting proper output.

```
 $cmd = "curl -i -F 
                account_id=12345 -F 
                authhash=BKPda_T497AX4EjBsk3ttw9OcOzk -F 
                audioFile=@CasioVoice.wav 
                https://url/upload";
        exec($cmd,$result);
```

Comment: what are you getting instead of the proper output?

Comment: You are getting correct thing:- `// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url/upload");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Nothing is showing on output.

Comment: @AlivetoDie OP wants to send an encoded form (```-F```, which also implies a ```POST``` request), and get back HTTP headers (```-i```). The converter site completely disregards these details.

Comment: @AlivetoDie If they are providing correct thing. where is my authHash, accountId and audio file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Comment: The only thing missing from the linked question is the ```-i``` part, you need CURLOPT_HEADER for that: ```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);```. Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: You could try https://curlconverter.com/php/ instead.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the comments:

> ```
> curl -i -F account_id=12345 -F authhash=BKPda_T497AX4EjBsk3ttw9OcOzk -F audioFile=@CasioVoice.wav  https://url/upload
> ```

is going to be

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://url/upload");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
       'account_id' => '12345',
       'authhash' => 'BKPda_T497AX4EjBsk3ttw9OcOzk',
       'audioFile' => new CURLFile('CasioVoice.wav')));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

And then you may have to fight with https, depending on the server's certification. If you need that, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` are some options to look into, but let's hope you will not need them.

Comment: The code is executed now. but my audio file is not pushing to the third party. I am using $filepath = '@' . realpath('/callRecord/CasioVoice.wav')

Comment: I have putted the correct authHash and account_id in curl call. but it giving me 401 error. While same thing I am doing on curl command. it is working. Please help where I am lacking?

Comment: no it's not, you're wrong. guys, stop upvoting this post, this is wrong. this would send a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-formatted request with no file attached whatsoever, OP's code is actually uploading a file, and using the `multipart/form-data`-format.

Comment: @hanshenrik yes, you are right, ```http_build_query``` was a trap. The ```@``` syntax is expected to work, so I just leave it be.

Comment: @ManeeshRao remove the ```http_build_query``` thing, that was a bad idea. Also, it is not clear if you want to get the response or pass it through your code - in the latter case ```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);``` should be commented/removed.

Comment: @tevemadar no, the @ syntax is NOT expected to work anymore. @ was deprecated in PHP 5.5 (in favor of CURLFile ) , was disabled-by-default in PHP 5.6 (see the CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD documentation), and completely removed in PHP7.

Comment: @hanshenrik great, it's PHP being PHP: ```CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ``` only says "*As of PHP 5.5.0, the @ prefix is deprecated and files can be sent using CURLFile. The @ prefix can be disabled for safe passing of values beginning with @ by setting the CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD option to TRUE.*"

Comment: @tevemadar damn, you're right. someone should fix the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS documentation.

Answer (score 0):

your PHP code try to execute curl with a bunch of newlines in the parameters, and the newlines are confusing curl. get rid of the newlines, and it should work.

```
$cmd = "curl -i -F account_id=12345 -F authhash=BKPda_T497AX4EjBsk3ttw9OcOzk -F audioFile=@CasioVoice.wav https://url/upload";
```

or use concatenation to avoid the newlines at runtime, while still having them in the source code,

```
 $cmd = "curl -i ".
        "-F account_id=12345 ".
        "-F authhash=BKPda_T497AX4EjBsk3ttw9OcOzk ".
        "-F audioFile=@CasioVoice.wav " .
        "https://url/upload";
```

, ps, you can also use php's libcurl wrapper to the same effect,

```
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array (
                "account_id" => 12345,
                "authhash" => "BKPda_T497AX4EjBsk3ttw9OcOzk",
                "audioFile" => new CURLFile ( "CasioVoice.wav" ) 
        ),
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://url/upload",
        CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT=>1
) );
curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );
```